Does Spark 3.X on kubernetes supports dynamic allocation
We are using EKS master as spark master and as of now we are using fixed number of executors.
Now we want to enable dynamic allocation, does it supports in case of EKS.
I've seen some blogs saying to create shuffle service in EKS as daemonset. Is it really required for dynamic allocation.

On k8s, you will need to set spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true as alternative to external shuffle service. It is described in Spark Configuraiton,  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation, option #2.

Im Able to achieve dynamic allocation on EKS as a Spark master with below configurations :
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
 .config("spark.executor.cores", sparkExecCores)
 .config("spark.executor.memory", sparkExecMemory)
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", sparkInitialExecutors)
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", sparkMinExecutors)
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", sparkMaxExecutors) 
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout", execIdleTimeout) 
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled", "true")
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout", cachedExecTimeout)
 .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.timeout", shuffleTrackingTimeout)

